# (4 Queens + 3 Pawns) vs (Entire Standard Army)

Tags: chess-variants, point-value

My club has recently been playing the variant [Etchessera](http://etchessera.com).  For those unfamiliar, this variant allows you to build an army consisting of a King and up to 39 points worth of pieces according to the following system:

- Pawn - 1pt
- Knight - 3pt
- Bishop - 3pt
- Rook   - 5pt
- Queen  - 9pt

While I realize that the relative point values are often listed differently, and can change based upon what other pieces remain, we were wondering if there should be a clear winner between the standard chess army and one consisting of 4 queens and 3 pawns.

[image]

Through our own games, the match-up appears to still be about equal provided the classic army plays defensive openings and forces a few trades.  However, my club is a very small sample size and I was looking to see if this has ever been explored elsewhere.

Comment: How do you decide the initial position of the nonstandard army?  Who moves first?

Comment: Pawns can be placed in any of the first 3 rows.  Any other piece must be placed in the back row.  White moves first unless black used less points to construct their army.

Comment: pawn on first row OK?  What's the rule on double-move (or even triple-move) privileges?

Comment: The complete rules can be found at http://etchessera.com/rules.html  While it doesn't explicitly say, we've interpreted them to read that it is possible to place pawns in the first row.  Also, we understand that a pawn can move two squares on its first move from any location.  Triple moving is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems that you're playing a saner version of what's
on that website, only the standard six chessmen.

Comment: That it means that I cannot choose to start with, say 13 knights, because there wouldn't be enough spots on the back rank to place them ? (I like knights...)

Comment: Right, you could only use a max of 7 Knights, since you would need room for the King.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A clarifying comment says "Pawns can be placed in any of the first 3 rows. 
Any other piece must be placed in the back row. White moves first unless 
black used less points to construct their army."  So the position I gave
earlier doesn't work, but since Black is allowed to move first with fewer than
39 points there's still a forced win:

```
[FEN "1b1qkqq1/8/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR b - - 0 0"]

1. Qxf2+ Kxf2 
2. Qh4+ g3 
3. Qgxg3+ hxg3 
4. Qxg3#
```

Comment: That's really interesting!  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I imagine knowing this this will lead my club to start the classic army setup with a few pawns already pushed to mitigate this.  But I guess that's the nature of asymmetrical build-your-own army games.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific position you show, I can well believe that the classical army
has an advantage: I've read that a second Queen tends to be redundant
and thus worth less than the first, so I'd expect a third and fourth
Queen to continue the pattern, assuming that the opponent's King
is not in immediate danger.  But if you can array your fantasy-draft
army anywhere you want in the first few rows you can win by force
even with fewer than 39 points:

```
[FEN "q3qr1k/b4q2/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 0"]

1. Nf3 Qaxf3
2. gxf3 Qxf3
3. d4 Qxf2+
4. Kd2 Qee3#
```

It even works with Re8 instead of the Qe8 
(though the mate takes a few moves longer).

Comment: 1 f3 lasts a bit longer; if Black doesn't have an immediately forced mate
  after Bxg1 or Qxf3 or Qf4 then add a Bd8 to the initial position
  to make sure (1 f3 Qaxf3 2 Nxf3 Qxf3 3 gxf3 Bh4#).

Comment: Thanks.  This variant doesn't allow you to place major pieces (non-pawns) in anything but the back row for that reason.  Consequently it takes at least a turn or two to setup for this.  During that time, White would have to form a sufficient defense.